# How to use additional file in Perl while we make exe

Tags: perl

I will add some extra file while I make .exe file using perl (PP). Please see my below code for making .exe file.

```
pp -gui -a 7z.exe -a 7z.dll -o gui_curl.exe gui_curl.pl
```

Both file are added when .exe build, But it does not work. I don't know why?

I used both file in my code, like below:-

```
system("7z.exe a $current_dir/$file_name.tar $current_dir");
system("7z.exe a $current_dir/$file_name.gz $current_dir/$file_name.tar");
```

Please suggest me how to use this file. I don't want to put this file outside from exe

Comment: "It does not work" is a bit short. Could you please add details, such as error messages or the behaviour of the produced exe file?

Comment: it does not give any error when we make exe file using pp command. my problem is:- after making exe file it does not 7z.exe and its dll file for create zip. May be i need to declare path of  7z.exe and its dll  or some like. Could you suggest me any idea

Comment: David Verdin could you help me on this problem ???

Comment: Does your code consists of only these two lines? If not, you might want to show the other ones.

Comment: Also: you should try to test whether your packaged file find the executable and dll, using -f for example.

Comment: No code is very long i can't put here :(. Because low "REPUTATION",

Comment: Okie dokie. Wait a little.

Comment: Re-reading the documentation of pp, it appears you're doing it wrong: it will help you pack yor perl executable with perl modules and distribute it. I doubt it will allow to add executables such as 7z. For one, you don't know where 7z expects to find its dll. If you just want to create a tar.gz file, you should rather use Archive::Tar module.

Comment: when i test file existence then it search outside of exe not inside of exe. Very confused why not work with inside exe

if i put both file in same direction then it work file but i don't want my program use outside file

Comment: PAR allow to add additional on your exe file using -a

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggested solution. It does not use 7zip which I have no idea how to make work within pp.

It's based on [Archive::Tar](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Archive-Tar-2.24/lib/Archive/Tar.pm) instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
use Archive::Tar;

my $current_dir = getcwd();
my $file_name = 'archive';

my @files_to_archive;

opendir(DIR, $current_dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
    push @files_to_archive, $file;
}

closedir(DIR);

my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
$tar->add_files(@files_to_archive);
$tar->write("$current_dir/$file_name.tgz", COMPRESS_GZIP);

my $extract_dir = '/tmp/test_arc';
mkdir $extract_dir unless (-d $extract_dir );
chdir $extract_dir;
$tar->extract('archive.tar');
```

Afterwards, you run

```
pp -o zipper.exe archive.pl -M Archive::Tar
```

and you should have your standalone archiver.

Comment: I am very thank full, But using this module when you extract tar file then it extract file, without any extension. That's why i use "7z". I already done it with this module, but it does not meet my requirement.

Comment: Wht do you mean "without any extension" ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to also extract files with the same script?

Comment: No, When you extract the gz file, Then the extracted file should be .tar. But it extract file with only archive name and it have no extension. I was done it with Archive::Tar.

Comment: Now, Only I want how to use any file inside of exe if I add using -M or -a

Comment: No, that's just the way you name your archive. When gunzipping a file, if it ends with ".gz", the resulting file is named after what is before ".gz". If it's called ".tgz" or ".tar.gz", you get a ".tar" file. Actually, I don't know if it's done when unzipping or when you zip with this extension. Anyway, look at my modified solution. You obtain a single .tar file as you wished.

Comment: And i won't be able to do more. I don't think you have a simple solution to embed 7zip in a perl packaged executable.